# Перебор массива с заданным условием

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x

Есть массив `test.csv`, где хранятся числа с запятой.

Нужно перебрать все числа, разбив на два столбца.

Условие следующее: если число `2 >=` числа `1` на `5%` в первый столбец, если число `2 <=` числа `1` на `5%` во второй столбец. Если условия не выполняются число в столбцы не попадает.Если число `2` выполняет одно из условий, то число `3` уже сравнивают с числом `2`. И так до конца списка.

```
number = [2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 8, 5, 7, 6, 9, 10, 1 ,3]
x = 6

for numbers in number:
    if numbers <= x:
        print (str(numbers) + " в Столбец №2" )
    elif numbers >= x:
        print(str(numbers) + " в Столбец №1" )
```

Так как занимаюсь Питоном совсем не давно то смог сварганить только это. Условие те же, а вот как их сделать я не знаю.

Comment: Если пар из ушей, значит уже пару сотен строк кода набили. Покажите, где у вас что не получается.

Comment: Если бы. На самом деле нечем особо похвалиться.

Comment: Я не понимаю как выполнить условие по отбору и потом опираться на прошедшее отбор число

Comment: Из описания задачи не очень понятно, что за массив 'test.csv', если в коде уже приведен список. Подозреваю, что чтение из массива (файла?) в список с помощью питоновского модуля csv  будет отдельной задачей (и вопросом, если что). Кстати что значит "числа с запятой"? Это целые числа через запятую, или же там действительные числа с десятичной запятой (а в питоне это точка, кстати).

Answer (score 1):

К примеру так:

```
In [38]: def calc(array):
    ...:     column_1, column_2 = [], []
    ...:     for i in range(1, len(array)):
    ...:         if ((array[i]-array[i-1])/array[i-1])*100 >= 5:
    ...:             column_1.append(array[i])
    ...:         elif ((array[i]-array[i-1])/array[i-1])*100 < 5:
    ...:             column_2.append(array[i])
    ...:     return column_1, column_2
```

Результат:

```
In [39]: calc([2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 8, 5, 7, 6, 9, 10, 1, 3])
Out[39]: ([6, 8, 10, 12, 7, 9, 10, 3], [8, 5, 6, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Если совсем по-простому:

```
number = [2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 8, 5, 7, 6, 9, 10, 1, 3]
x = number[0]
column_1, column_2 = [], []

for i in number[1:]:
    if i >= x+x*0.05:
        column_1.append(i)
        x = i
    elif i <= x-x*0.05:
        column_2.append(i)
        x = i

print('Столбец № 1: {0}\nСтолбец № 2: {1}'.format(column_1, column_2))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, за вашу помощь. Попробую более точно обрисовать ситуацию. Есть массив: number = [2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 8, 5, 7, 6, 9, 10,1 ,3], его перебрать надо по следующему правилу(беру из текущих цыфр): берем "6" и сравниваем это число с числом "2", если "6" больше "2" на 5% и более отправляем число "6" в столбец№1, если "6" меньше "2" на 5% и более отправляем в столбец№2. Если "6" не выполняет ни одного условия оставляем без столбца. Т.к. "6" больше "2" на 5% и более , то следующее число "8" сравниваем с "6". итак весь список. На выходе имеем два столбца

Comment: Вооо, теперь понятно, отредактировал ответ

Comment: Зачем там `else: pass`?

Comment: @Alban можно и без него :)